# Highlight multiple HTML elements using Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using jQuery, I can highlight a single HTML element by adding css to the element like following:

```
$("div:contains('simple')").css("border", "4px solid blue");
```

I am wondering whether I can highlight multiple elements at the same time, like

```
<h2>A title here</h2>
<div>Some content here</div>
<h2>A another title here</h2>
<div>Some more content here</div>
```

How can I highlight the first `h2` together with the first `div`?

I know I can create a parent `div` to hold the elements, but the newly created `div` may affect the original layout, like

```
<p>I want to highlight <span>this</span> <strong>and this</strong></p>
```

I need to set the `display` property for the parent `div` according to the context, right? Is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Can I get a single highlight box(or other highlight effect, like background) for the two elements?

Comment: `$("h2:first, div:first").css("border", "4px solid blue")` cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate different selectors with a comma:

```
$("div:contains('simple'), h2:contains('simple')").css("border", "4px solid blue");
```

Here are docs for this:
http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

> Can I get a single highlight box(or other highlight effect, like
>   background) for the two elements?

That depends on your HTML heavily. Taking your h2/div example you can make it look like it has common border once both H2 and div have same width:
CSS:

```
div.highlighted, h2.highlighted {
   border:4px solid blue;
}
div.highlighted {
    border-top:none;/*remove top border for a div*/
}
div.highlighted {
    border-bottom:none;/*remove bottom border for a h2*/
}
```

and than JS:

```
$("div:contains('simple'), h2:contains('simple')").addClass("highlighted");
```

In other situations you may need to do something else.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve this. One way would be to add classes to the first h2 and div, and use that as your selector:

```
$(".class-name-that-you-have-added").css("border", "4px solid blue");
```

A good read would be this: [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)